# How to pronounce 1ターン?

Tags: pronunciation, loanwords, counters

I've seen the phrase 1ターン1度 "once per turn" used in the Yu-Gi-Oh! Card game, so it seems like ターン is a legit counter. But I'm not sure how to pronounce it. From what I've googled so far, some people pronounce it like いったーん which is odd because ターン is a gairaigo.

So how do you pronounce 1ターン?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both いちたーん and いったーん are valid. (As an aside, わんたーん is also very common, especially when it's part of a longer phrase like 1ターンキル.)

There may be exceptions I'm not aware of, but basically foreign counters/units that start with K, T or P can be read both いち○○ and いっ○○.

- 1カラット: いちからっと・いっからっと
- 1キロ: いちきろ・いっきろ
- 1テスラ: いちてすら・いってすら
- 1トラック: いちとらっく・いっとらっく
- 1トン: いちとん・いっとん
- 1ペソ: いちぺそ・いっぺそ
- 1ポンド: いちぽんど・いっぽんど

Comment: Speaking as an avid TCG player (Magic: The Gathering in my case), in my experience, わんたーん is the most common >_<